# PHP csv header key replacement in while loop

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

Im trying to replace the `'category names'` with its respective `'category id'` when the time of importing the CSV
into mysql table.

can someone help me with right approach of replacing the csv headers with whitelist IDs in foreach php?

the below is my script which i tried,
the keys are not getting replaced as expected.

the reason why i do this name replacement with id is, there might be some minor spelling changes made to category names in master table in future frequently.

so at that time i need to update the batch table aswell which is not a good idea, to avoid that, iam replacing category name with id and inserting in batch table.

```
<?php
    $category_id = $post['category_id'];
    //query master table and get category details
    $header_qry = $con->prepare("SELECT category_name,category_id FROM category where category_id=:category_id and status=1");
    $header_qry->bindParam(':category_id', $category_id);
    $header_qry->execute();

    while ($header_qry_data = $header_qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $header_names[] = $header_qry_data['category_name'];
        $header_name_id[] = $header_qry_data;
    }

    $keys = [];
    $csvheders = fgetcsv($source);

    foreach ($csvheders AS $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $keys[] = $value;
        }
    }

    if(count(array_intersect($header_names, $csvheders)) !== count($csvheders)) {
        $messageSession[] = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => 'Columns Mismatch');
        $_SESSION['alert_messages'] = $messageSession;
        header("location:cat_upload.php");
    } else {

        function searchMultiArrays($val, $array) {
            foreach ($array as $element) {
                if ($element['category_name'] == $val) {
                    return $element['category_id'];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        while ($csvdata = fgetcsv($source)) {
            foreach ($csvdata as $k => $v) {
                unset($csvdata[$k]);

                // set the key (based on the keys array established above)
                $keyvals = $keys[$k];
                $new_key = searchMultiArrays("$keyvals", $header_name_id);
                $csvdata[$new_key] = $v;
            }

            $cat_details = json_encode($csvdata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

            //insert category details into batch table
            $insert_json = $con->prepare("insert into batch_detail (batch_id,cat_details) values (:batch_id,:cat_details)");
            $insert_json->bindParam(':batch_id', $batch_id);
            $insert_json->bindParam(':cat_details', $cat_details);
            $insert_json->execute();
        }
        $messageSession[] = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Details Uploaded Successfully');
        $_SESSION['alert_messages'] = $messageSession;
        header("location:upload_summary.php");
    }
```

Comment: Can you.edit your question and add some indenting to make it easier to read?

Comment: @Andreas, hope it is easy to read now